how to change filter to all layers in GIMP?
Asking here cause GIMP IRC is almost dead and their nowhere else
Theoretically or not: I'm making an animation with 50 or more scenes/images/layers and want to filter all layers at once
by filter i mean: saturation, desaturation, changing brightness, changing contrast, changing temperature, colorizing all layers, etc…
Ever possible? "filters" dialog applies to only a single layer but whoever would like to filter each 50 layers manually?
BTW: I thought already of using ImageMagick but AFAIK it doesn't work on GIFs/animations although I might be wrong, if so - correct me cause I'm a noobo.

BTW: it's a real question - I'm trying to change palette of an animation but GIMP doesn't catch colors properly so I thought of changing brightness/saturation for palette to work properly.

may i know why someone edited just to remove markup? i did it specially to show importance of sentences… (for people - see revisions page cause that one is importanter)

The colours won't be editable if it's in Indexed colour. Convert to RGB first.  There's no built-in functionality that can filter all layers at once.  You will either need a script, or a plugin like BIMP, or you could could just use shortcuts to apply the same filter repeatedly. Select the top layer, apply the filter, press the down arrow key to go to the next layer down. Press Ctrl+F to apply the filter again. Repeat the key presses until finished.

haven't i said i can covert back to RGB and that i want to do it?

OK, I've added an answer. Oops I see you have chosen it already

If you are in Indexed mode, the filters won't work properly. Convert to RGB first.  There's no functionality built-in that will filter all layers in one go. You'll either need a script like Xenoid's suggestion, or a plugin like BIMP.  Anyway, here's a way that is manual - no scripts/plugins.  You only have 50 layers, so this is perfectly doable in a minute or two.

Select the topmost layer.

Apply the filter

Use the down arrow key to select the next layer down

Hit Ctrl+F to repeat the last filter


repeat steps 3 and 4 until finished.

A solution is to:

merge all your layers into a single layer (sprite sheet)
perform the editing on that single layer
split it back to individual layers

The ofn-layer-tiles script will perform both Merge and Split operations.
With the experimental Gimp 2.99, you can use multiple layer selection.

maybe something addon-less? i like vanillas :)

If the image is color-indexed, you can edit the palette, but this is not for the faint of the heart. Also, many tools remember their settings so re-applying the same tool with the same values on all layers is tedious but easy.

Otherwise the semi-official Gimp forum is here.

i have 2 palettes. image is already indexed although i can revert it back to RGB, palettes i have from LOSPEC (yep, i do pixel arts) and i have each only once what'd mean that i'd need to download it again but probably i'd had a trouble in it cause LOSPEC palette list doesn't have ability to search by name…

If the image is color-indexed, then Windows > Dockable dialogs > Color map and you can edit the colors.

thx. gonna see :)

To apply a filter to all layers in GIMP:

Duplicate the current layer.
Merge all layers using "Layer" > "Merge Visible Layers."
Apply the filter to the merged layer.
Undo the merge to restore individual layers if needed.


Maybe you could suggest ways to "undo the merge".

To apply a filter to all layers in GIMP, select "Filters" from the menu, then choose "Repeat Last" or use the keyboard shortcut Shift+Ctrl+F.
